# best place for save security info in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i create a web application with angualr 8 .

i need to guard or routes and pages with dynamic accessLevel .

for example i check in the route , if user have access to this route , open it but shout he/she into the login page .

i have this list and i save it in local storage and every time need to check the AccessLevel i get all list from localstorage and check it .

now i think the local storage not a good place for save securityInfo .

every body have suggestion for best and secyre place for save this info ?????

Comment: You should use cookies or browser storage

Answer (score 1):

Ideally for this you should have to have seperate API. And from the your angular application. You can use `CanActivate` route guard and eachtime when use trying to go to a specific page you can check it for access.

Another option is to keep a global `service` maintained to keeping user access data. Once after the user logs in fetch data from the backend of your applciation(One time API call) and store it in the global data service variable and returned it as a observable when ever you needs it. Whenever the user accessing a specific route check for the relevent authorization in you angular application. Since the global data `service` is available at the `root` level it will have access to all the `components` thorughout.

Another approach is create and store the authorization details in `NgRxStore`. And use those values stored in it when user accessing a specific `route`.

Comment: can we use localstorage for keeping user access data

Comment: Yes you can.. For ex: like access token

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create the API for this purpose.Then while deciding the access level you can call the API for that